# Installing Rails on Ubuntu 12.10 VPS - errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I try every tutorial on web but still nothing... when i try to :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

i see this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                        libc-dev
               Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

sudo aptitude .. doesnt work.. any sudo apt-get -f .. doesnt work... i add repository to source.list , do update and still nothing...

Comment: See [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, please make a backup of your current sources.list, delete the original and try with this one:

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security restricted main multiverse universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates restricted main multiverse universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-proposed restricted main multiverse universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-backports restricted main multiverse universe

Then do 'sudo apt-get update'  and try installing again.

Answer (score 0):

this is a clear dependency problem, there are a few ways to solve that, one is to install 'aptitude' , it will do a part of the job for you by checking all possible paths in the dependency tree to solve your problem. 
In most cases apt-get should have the versions of the packages available and solve the dependencies by itself, in this case the problem will only be fixed by adding the correct repositories to sources.list, i think that you will need to change your repositories or add some new ones, sometimes adding one from a different ubuntu version can help.
One more option (but not desirable) is the use of apt-pinning, but the last one should be enough for you.

Comment: i add new list of repository but nothing change ... i add :

Answer (score 0):

deb http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

this repository doesnt work and i have that same error